# Using ws-federation login to login.srf using third-party SSO saml assertion, I get AADSTS50008: SAML token is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-online, login, saml

My goal is to get a binary security token for Office365 so that I can generate fedauth/rtfa cookies to access Sharepoint Online REST/Soap Web Services.

I have set up PingFederate to secure my sharepoint online instance.

I have generated a SAML1.1 assertion using PingFederate SSO. I send that saml assertion to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf endpoint

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Form params:

    wa = wsignin1.0

    wresult = (saml1.1 assertion xml)
```

I get this error code/message every time:

`AADSTS50008: SAML token is invalid.`

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a step, or misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I figured out this issue.

I was copy pasting the saml assertion across an email. and i think the text formatting got messed up. Once I used text file attachment instead, it doesn't throw this error anymore.